# Как перезапустить бота кодом, при нажатии inline кнопки(pytelegrambotapi)?

Tags: python, бот, telebot

Есть Telegram бот, код:

```
import telebot 
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("*****")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def send_welcome(message):
  global markup, DELETEuserName, DELETEuserName1 #делаю переменную глобальной, чтобы она была видна в остальных функциях. Переменные с приставкой DELETE нужны для того, чтобы удалить сообщения от бота
  markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
  resetDataKey = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Сбросить", callback_data="resetData")
  markup.add(resetDataKey)
  userName = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте, введите имя")
  DELETEuserName = userName.chat.id
  DELETEuserName1 = userName.message_id
  bot.register_next_step_handler(userName, userSurNameFUNC)
def userSurNameFUNC(message):
  userName1 = message.text
  global userName, DELETEuserSurName, DELETEuserSurName1 #проделываю эту махинацию, чтобы сообщения превращались в тип String и конкатенировались
  userName = userName1
  userSurName = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Теперь введите фамилию", reply_markup=markup)
  DELETEuserSurName = userSurName.chat.id
  DELETEuserSurName1 = userSurName.message_id
  bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
  bot.delete_message(DELETEuserName, DELETEuserName1)
  bot.register_next_step_handler(userSurName, endProgrammFUNC)
def endProgrammFUNC(message):
  userSurName1 = message.text
  global userSurName, DELETEendProgramm, DELETEendProgramm1
  userSurName = userSurName1
  endProgramm = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вас зовут " + userName + " " + userSurName)
  DELETEendProgramm  = endProgramm.chat.id
  DELETEendProgramm1 = endProgramm.message_id
  bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
  bot.delete_message(DELETEuserSurName, DELETEuserSurName1)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def inline_handler(call):
  if call.data == "resetData":
    bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
    userName = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте, введите имя")
    DELETEuserName = userName.chat.id
    DELETEuserName1 = userName.message_id
    try:
      try:
        pass
      except:
        try:
          bot.delete_message(DELETEuserSurName, DELETEuserSurName1)
        except:
          bot.delete_message(DELETEendProgramm, DELETEendProgramm1)
    except:
      pass
    bot.register_next_step_handler(userName, userSurNameFUNC)
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Когда я запускаю бота, с первого раза всё работает стабильно, но когда я нажимаю сбросить, и хочу начать по новой (начать вводить имя), то бот работает по предыдущему запросу, и думает что я ввёл фамилию.

Соответственно сначала бот пишет "Введите имя", а потом он думает что я ввожу фамилию, и выдаёт результат "Вас зовут" + имя и фамилия введённая пользователем, затем такую ошибку:

```
2021-10-31 21:53:34,798 (__init__.py:663 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request
 to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request
: message to delete not found"
```

Как можно при нажатии inline кнопки сбросить работу программы, перезапустить бота и начать сначала? Чтобы при каждом нажатии на inline кнопку, скрипт будто закрыли и открыли заново. Не знаю как сделать это кодом, чтобы бот работал без остановки 24/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно повторно вызывать функцию `send_welcome` прямо из `inline_handler`, которая ловит нажатие кнопки сброса.

А в самой функции `send_welcome` сбрасывать все зарегистрированные обработчики с помощью вызова `bot.clear_step_handler(message)`.

Тогда если `send_welcome` вызвана первый раз, никаких обработчиков еще не установлено и ничего не произойдет, а если повторно - они будут сброшены, как и требуется.

Вот пример рабочего кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def send_welcome(message):
    global DELETEuserName1
    bot.clear_step_handler(message)
    userName = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте, введите имя")
    DELETEuserName1 = userName.message_id
    bot.register_next_step_handler(userName, userSurNameFUNC)


def userSurNameFUNC(message):
    global userName, DELETEuserSurName, DELETEuserSurName1
    userName = message.text
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    resetDataKey = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Сбросить", callback_data="resetData")
    markup.add(resetDataKey)
    userSurName = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Теперь введите фамилию", reply_markup=markup)
    DELETEuserSurName = userSurName.chat.id
    DELETEuserSurName1 = userSurName.message_id
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, DELETEuserName1)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(userSurName, endProgrammFUNC)


def endProgrammFUNC(message):
    global userSurName, DELETEendProgramm, DELETEendProgramm1
    userSurName = message.text
    endProgramm = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вас зовут " + userName + " " + userSurName)
    DELETEendProgramm = endProgramm.chat.id
    DELETEendProgramm1 = endProgramm.message_id
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)
    bot.delete_message(DELETEuserSurName, DELETEuserSurName1)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def inline_handler(call):
    if call.data == "resetData":
        bot.delete_message(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
        send_welcome(call.message)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Чрезмерно Вам благодарен!